# Lazy load local image if source not passed as a prop

Tags: reactjs

I have a component with a background image. The image source could be passed to the component as a prop. If the component doesn't get an image source through that prop then it should use a default image. All images are local.

What I want to do is to load and use a default image only if no source was passed. Otherwise use the passed source and not load the default image. The idea is not to store two images inside the component in case the component gets that image source prop.

Here I have 2 question. First, is it even a good idea since all images are local? Second: how to implement that conditional image loading? My solution seems to be a bit complicated

```
export const MyComponent = ({source}) => {
    const [src, setSrc] = useState();

    useEffect(() => {
        if(!source) {
            import('./path/defaultImage.png')
           .then(({ default }) => setSrc(default)
        }
    }, []);
```

Comment: What's wrong with `{props.source || './path/defaultImage.png'}`?

Comment: @palindrom ummm shouldn't I import image first to use it's source?